# Matplotlib variable issues

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am almost brand-new to Python and matplotlib, and so have been working on adapting an example from the Python documentation for a graph that I need to complete. However, I get undefined name errors for the `rect1` and `rect2` calls and for ax in the `ax.text`. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the values not transferring across function definitions, but I can't figure out the proper syntax. Any ideas?

P.S. I can supply additional information if necessary; this is my first post of this sort.

```
from inventoryClass import stockItem

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotInventory(itemRecords):

    stockBegin = []
    stockFinish = []    
    stockID = []    
    stockItems = []
    for rec in itemRecords.values() :
        stockBegin.append(rec.getStockStart)
        stockFinish.append(rec.getStockOnHand)
        stockID.append(rec.getID)
        stockItems.append(rec.getName)
    N = len(stockBegin)    


ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, stockBegin, width, color='r')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, stockFinish, width, color='y')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Inventory')
ax.set_title('Stock start and end inventory, by item')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels((str(stockID[0]), str(stockID[1]), str(stockID[1])))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Start', 'End'))

def autolabel(rects) :

    for rect in rects :
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            '%d' % int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables rects1 and rects2 only exist in the scope of plotInventory and so python doesn't know what you're referring to by 'rects1'. There are two possible ways to fix this:

1. You can *return* the values so they are available in the global scope:

   ```
   def plotInventory(itemRecords):
       # ... code ... #
       return rects1, rects2

   rects1, rects2 = plotInventory(records)
   autolabel(rects1)
   autolabel(rects2)

   plt.show()
   ```
2. You can just call autolabel from inside plotInventory:

   ```
   def plotInventory(itemRecords):
       # ... code ... #
       autolabel(rects1)
       autolabel(rects2)
   ```

As for ax, you have the same problem and the same solutions, except that you need to pass ax into autolabel, eg:

```
def autolabel(ax, rects):
    # ... code ... #

ax, rects1, rects2 = plotInventory(records)
autolabel(ax, rects1)
autolabel(ax, rects2)
```

Remember to return ax from plotInventory as well!

Comment: Thanks for the help, that does indeed solve my problem. Cheers!